# unable to apply jquery filter

Tags: jquery, list

I m un-animating a list using this code...

```
function unanimate_li() {
  $li.filter(':last')
    .animate({
      height:  'hide',
      opacity: 'hide'
    }, 1000, function() {
      unanimate_li();
    });
  $li = $li.not(':last');
}
```

I have set up the li using this code

```
$li = $("ol#update > li");
$li = $li.filter(':gt(4)').filter(':lt('+ size + ')');
```

Now when i try to do this i cannot get the 5th li(4th on zero based) to remove
It removes the sixth li
The example [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/divcomment.jsp)

And when the second time i do the update it goes on to **infinite loop**

I cannot understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. When you call either the `animate` or the `unanimate` function your callback calls the same function again and seems like it should create an infinite loop.

Also, I noticed your `unanimate` function uses `$li` that is updated multiple times in the script. This became very confusing to me as to what it ultimately contained. So I modified the function to grab the current `li` tags and work from there.

Another thing I noticed is that you are using `:last` to find the last `li` which I believe is also grabbing the hidden `li`'s, so either remove the hidden ones or use `:visible`

Try these functions:

```
function animate_li(){
 $("ol#update > li:first")
  .animate({
   height:  'show',
   opacity: 'show'
  }, 5
 );
}

function unanimate_li(){
 $("ol#update > li:visible:last")
  .animate({
   height:  'hide',
   opacity: 'hide'
  }, 1000, function(){
   // $(this).remove(); // uncomment this line if you want to remove the li
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the :visible part...
this definitely works but i have to remove the last n number of messages and parametrize the function unanimate_li for multi-use...
please reply... thanks...

Comment: Did you try passing the value of `$li` as a parameter? `function unanimate_li($li){...}` or just pass the number of elements to remove, like `unanimate_li(4)` then in the function use `function unanimate_li(num){ $('ol#update > li:visible:gt(' + num + ')') ... }`

Comment: I have updated the link...http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/divcomment.jsp
on first update it works fine.. on second update it does not...can u please check with firebug and rectify...

Comment: Sorry, I guess I totally missed the comment above, did you find your solution?